# Node.js : How does Node.js know which HTML file to use?

Tags: node.js

In Node.js when using with express I gave the line `app.use(express.static(__dirname+ '/views'))`. I have only provided the directory. How does node know that the main content of my file will be in index.html(I know this because no where I have written to show index.html still when I type `localhost:8082` it opens up index.html)? What if I don't have an index.html and if it is so, what algorithm it uses to choose which file to open from a particular directory.

Comment: `index.html` is the default value of the `index` option. you can change it to whatever you like. `app.use(express.static(__dirname+ '/views', {index: 'blasphemy.idunno'}))` Knowing that, it's easy to assume that if you left it at default and didn't have an index.html, you'd get a 404.

Comment: Well that answers my question. Could you write that up as an answer?

Comment: To add here is some supporting documentation https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static?_ga=1.218469595.315231849.1437421075#index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**index.html** is the default value of the *index* option, you can change it to whatever you like.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+ '/views', {index: 'blasphemy.idunno'}))
```

Knowing that, it's easy to assume that if you left it at default and didn't have an **index.html**, you'd get a 404.